# Lazy Loading Drupal's Core JS files

Tags: javascript, drupal, web

For a mobile site, we are planning to load JS files through Require.js. I' am curious to know if there is any method available to load Drupals's core JS files (drupal.js) in asynchronous way?

Answer (score 0):

this module can help you [Asynchronous JavaScript](https://drupal.org/project/async_js)